# motionEnded not called in appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to integrate shake feature throughout the app. So I am doing everything in appDelegate. I need to push a viewController, I am able to push in motionBegan, but i wanted to do it motionEnded. yes motion ended does work in a view controller, but in app delegate it is not being called.
Doing as

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
```

motionEnded not called

```
-(void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
        NSLog(@"motionEnded called");
    }
}
```

motionBegan called

```
-(void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
        NSLog(@"motionBegan called");
    }
}
```

Comment: posting notification could help I guess

Comment: i havenot worked that much with notification i tried addingObserver "DeviceShaken" in applicationDidBecomeActivie but no gain

Comment: did you solve your issue? was answer helpful?

Comment: i am moved to some other part of the project, the answer was gud so i upvote, i will let you know when i get on this issue and will mark it the right answer if it is.

Answer (score 1):

you could basically register your `viewController` for `applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or any depending on your needs

for example in your `viewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method you could register it for notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

and implement this method in your class, your `myMethod` will call everytime your application will become active

```
-(void) myMethod(){
 // do your stuff
}
```

finally un-register viewController from the notification in dealloc method

```
-(void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```